# How to impove mysql query performance by node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Now I want to query mysql by ([node.js mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)), it costs 10s when I first query the data, but next time it costs less time.

```
router.get('/getStationsInfo1', function(req, res, next) {
    var nowTime = req.query.nowTime;
    var query = 'select stationid, timestamp,precipitation from db where timestamp = ? order by timestamp asc;'
    mysqlPool.query(query, [nowTime], function(error, results) {

        if (error) {

            res.send({

                code: 0,
                data: ''
            })
        }
        res.send({
            code: 1,
            data: results
        })
    });
})
```

Comment: add LIMIT to the query?

Comment: 10s on first query and subsecond time soon after it is likely to be just mysql query cache at work. True performance improvement needs proper indexing in sql table. Use `EXPLAIN <your_query>` to get more insight.

Comment: @yBrodsky Sorry, I am not clearly about the LIMITS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can e.g. Using a suitable query builder I always use [Knex](http://knexjs.org/) which works efficiently.

This is how you create the query builder:

```
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host: config.database_manager.host,
        user: config.database_manager.user,
        password: config.database_manager.password,
        database: config.database_manager.database
    }
});
```

and then you can do that...

```
async function addEntry (table, array) {
    return await knex (table) .insert (array);
}
```

Comment: I try the Knex, but it did not work well. I think it is based on mysql.

Comment: it dont improve the perfromance of the database just the performance of the connection